# Alternativa a iFrame / embed - Insertar contenido en otra web

Tags: javascript, php, html, fetch, jsonp

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto para visualizar una serie de fotos en 360º.

El producto final es un visor. (No es mas que una pagina web `HTML,JS,CSS`) que solicitan dados a `PHP` médiate `Json`

Dichos visores los insertamos a paginas web de nuestros clientes mediante un `iframe` (tambien he probado con `<embed>`)

```html
<iframe src="https://orbitvu.co/share/umfMRU9aUdxC9NvT9uneUe/200261/orbittour/view" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Esto hace que el estilo del `iframe` dependa del css de la pagina padre, sin contar que algunas webs no permiten `iframes`. tampoco permite hacer seguimiento mediante Google Analytics, etc.

Adicionalmente he probado con la `función` `Load` de `JQuery` pero salta la politica CORS

`<div id="homePage"></div>`

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
        $('#homePage').load('//orbitvu.co/share/umfMRU9aUdxC9NvT9uneUe/200261/orbittour/view');             
});
```

He encontrado un ejemplo. una empresa que utilizan un `cdn`.   implementan un `div`  con un `id` y una clase `css` e importan un documento  `script` con `jsonp` en la pagina padre. **(No tengo ni idea de como lo hacen, pero funciona)**

```html
<div id="orbittour-umfMRU9aUdxC9NvT9uneUe" class="orbittour-container">

</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="//orbitvu.co/share/umfMRU9aUdxC9NvT9uneUe/200261/orbittour/script"></script>
```

alguien tiene experiencia en este campo  ?

Comment: Lo que harías con jsonp es hacer lo que hace googleMaps por ejemplo, que el "cliente" cargue un javascript remoto.

Comment: Al estar el script en el cliente, puede acceder al html. Por eso te dicen, pon un div con cierto id específico. De cualquier manera esto no escapa al problema del css del cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he resuelto

Primero el cliente debe agregar  un `div` con un `id` unico  lo gestionas tu  y  luego debes pasar dicho `id` a un `script`  cuyo atributo  `src` sea un documento `php`. obiamente  la salida de ese documento sera un ´.js´ valido.

paso 1  (lo dicho este codigo deberia agregar el cliente)

> id unico eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJI

```html
<div class="test-embed" id="eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJI" style="width: 100%; aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;"></div>
<script src="https://dominio.com/embed/index.php?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJI&capa=1" ></script>
```

Paso 2 : En php leemos la plantilla `js` con la que vamos a responder

```php
<?php

//leemos el documento js  que luego vamos a imprimir

$plantilla =  file_get_content("resp.js");

//hacemos sustituciones o cosas   antes de imprimir


header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
echo $plantilla; 


?>
```

Paso 3 : esta es la plantilla

```
//inyectamos el CSS en el body
var element = document.createElement("link");
element.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
element.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
element.setAttribute(
  "href",
  "https://TAG_DOMINIO_VALUE/css/ruta-printer.css"
);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(element);

//pintamos el visor en el div
var tacktilcontainer = document.getElementById("TAG_TOKEN_VALUE");

tacktilcontainer.innerHTML = `
<!--INICIO_PLANTILLA-->
    <!--href="/plantillas/embed/index.htm"
<!--FIN_PLANTILLA-->
`;
```